# Is it possible to send a text message (SMS) from my PC, using my phone?

Tags: windows-10, windows-phone, sms

I am running Windows 10 and have a Lumia 1020 running Windows Phone 8.1.

As MS have brought in tighter device integration, is it possible I can use my PC to send (and view) text messages on my phone? i.e. I want my PC to act as a repeater to my phone.

If I need to plug my phone in to the PC via USB that's OK.

Comment: Broke my Windows phone and using ubuntu right now cannot test it. But there are claims it can be done. See [this](http://mspoweruser.com/how-to-send-and-receive-sms-from-a-windows-10-pc/) Also might get better audience at Windows Phone site

Comment: @pun Yeah I'm not sure if this would have a WP-specific answer or would be a Windows 10 OS feature

Comment: It says so `With the release of Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview Build 14327, Microsoft has enabled the ability to send and receive text messages from your phone directly from your Windows 10 PC’s.`

Comment: It used to be common before smartphones – you could connect most 'dumb'phones over USB and they'd show up as a _modem_, with some special [AT commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#GSM) for SMS and the like.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you have to use Cortana, to view messages you install this program here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/app/9wzdncrfjbq6?tduid=(1ea0e9a9945b4614495df9d38465c78d)(235158)(2503931)()()

Once installed and linked up and you have Cortana Enabled you open Cortana and type "Send Text To" this should then ask you for a phone number/message you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

Few carriers like AT&T (AT&T Messages online) and Verizon have a web based texting service that uses your number and allow you to send texts via PC. Apart from this, you can also try third-party apps like [mysms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/mysms-text-from-computer-messaging/9wzdncrfhwdc) to send text messages using your Windows 10 PC. You need to install "mysms" app on your Windows 10 phone too, but I'm not sure whether you can access your phone or not because in the comment section you mentioned that your phone is broken. Cortana can be used to send text messages via Windows 10 PC but for this your phone must be running Windows 10 too.